# Why use Dapper if I don't want to write my query on sql

Tags: orm

The project I am working on has 90% of the business logic in stored procedure. I looked at Dapper as a possible path to move some of these business rules to the Application layer. The benefits to me are evident, in that I can do unit testing etc etc.

Dapper seems to help with mapping objects, to classes through sql queries. This is not enough for me, because I'd like to build my queries into an application class like service, and then unit test them before I go to my Repository( aka Dapper). 
I'd expect the ORM to translate my query into sql. Dapper seams not to be meant to be used this way. So I wonder what is the point if I still have to build all my business logic in sql.

My question, is do I need a different ORM like hibernate? I guess I am looking for some guidance on how to evaluate this tool.

Comment: The Title might me misleading. I am not trying to dismiss Dapper. I want to use it, but I want to be able to test my queries through unit tests, not just integration tests.

Comment: What kind of ORM being used shouldnt matter. The business logic belongs to an application layer of some kind, decoupled from the database, repository interface DI:ed into the app layer. Unit test the business logic in the app layer. Intergation test the repository layer for the CRUD operations. Thats how I'd prefer working with the issue (been in that particlar situation quite recently...)

Comment: @Erion A *real* repository works at a higher level than the ORM. 10 years ago repository classes contained SqlCommand objects and mapping code but nowadays all that is provided by EF's DbContext or Dapper. Putting a "generic repository" on top of NH or EF makes things harder, not easier to write and test.

Comment: @Erion as for testing, what do you want to test? The code that calls the repository, the code *inside* the repository, or the ORM itself? A repo method that returns preferred customers could be `GetAllPreferred()=>ctx.Customers.Where(c=>c.IsPreferred).ToArray()`. Unit testing that would require pointint the ORM to a test source (eg a List<Customer>) instead of the actual database

Comment: I guess I want to unit test the queries that I am building. I see stored procedures that do 6/7 joins. where I could do similar work with Linq over a repository pattern and able to test it, but eventually I want the execution of the query to run in the database. I have worked with NHibernate for a long time, so am I indoctrinated? Integration tests for the simpler code. Maybe break up the entities into aggregates and then query that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience is that ORM frameworks exist on a spectrum of features and sophistication, often with inversely related compromises in speed and ease of use.

For me, Dapper is right at the end of the spectrum in terms of features and sophistication but with the trade-off that it's speed is exceptional. That's not to say that Dapper is unsophisticated and feature-less, just that it doesn't have features like sessions, query building, etc. that you will find in ORMs at the other end of that spectrum, e.g. NHibernate.

If you want an ORM that will build SQL queries based on an object-oriented domain model, then Dapper is not for you. NHibernate, Entity Framework, LLBLGen and ORMLite(?) are options you can look into. N.b. I expect there are others I've missed.

Comment: I guess, my confusion comes with the following usecase. Let's say I have 6 entities and I need to query for all of them. With repository pattern, and dapper, I'd create the mappers, for these entities, and then I'd have to query for joins of these. Now my repository will have to build the joins. The query would be a literal which then I take the result. But basically for me the query is the business logic, which I'd rather unit test. Aren't I loosing value here. Just asking

Comment: If you model your entities as classes and create the appropriate relationships between them, these classes and relationships can be 'mapped' by an ORM. Then the ORM builds the queries, with appropriate joins for you.

Comment: thanks, I just have been working with nhibernate for a long time and now I am working on a product where we are trying to build microservices pattern. I did more reading and now I see that Dapper is a tool that might not do Linq-to-sql code generation through IQuareble and it doesn't try to. I just assumed IQuarable was a good thing. I am not sold that I need to start using IEnubarable because I really liked the delegation of execution that I get with IQuarable but I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have a look at SQL Plus Dot Net. It is entity framework in reverse, that is, where entity framework build SQL statements from your C# code, SQL+ .net builds C# code from your SQL.
It truly is the first real innovation in data access in quite a while.